# Need help returning a json string after a successful jquery $.post()

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am posting to a php page that is returning the following json encoded string

```
{"msg":"Hi {{full_name}}, <br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\n  It was nice meeting you."}
```

I had added that json object in the `<script> </script>`

However when run the `$.post()` and try to output data.msg it says `undefined`.

Here is the full code

```
  $.post("mass_messaging.php",{template_id: template_id})

        .done(function(data){

            console.log(data.msg)
            //Outputs undefined??? 


        });
```

Below is a snippet of my html code

```
<script>

addMustachePlaceHolder();

{"msg":"Hi {{full_name}}, <br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\n  It was nice meeting you."}

</script>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `I had added that json object in the <script> </script>` I don't understand what you mean? `addMustachePlaceHolder();

{"msg":"Hi {{full_name}}, <br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\n  It was nice meeting you."}` This isn't valid js

Comment: I mean that i added the json object wrapped in the <script> tags. I was thinking that its the only way it will get parsed but apparently not.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to parse the json as it is a string and you need an object. jQuery can do that automatically if you set the data type:

```
$.post("mass_messaging.php", {template_id: template_id}, function(){}, "json")
                                                                       ^^^^^^ here
```

Apart from that it is not entirely clear what you are returning. You should only return one valid json string from your php script and nothing else; no script tags, javascript, etc.

Comment: `Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).` and looks like it is an object, not a string. But that's really not clear what OP is doing regarding posted code

Comment: @A.Wolff I know, but there seem to be a lot of problems here on SO with unparsed json. Anyway, the output should definitely be checked as well.

Comment: @jeroen. Thanks for the reply. I have tried that and still giving undefined. I also made sure I am only returning json. When I output data to the console.log i get this {"msg":"Hi {{full_name}}, <br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\n  It was nice meeting you."}

Comment: @jeroen How do I parse it as a string?

Comment: @json2021 That looks like a string and not like an object, what does the console say exactly?

Comment: @jeroen the console says,
{"msg":"Hi {{full_name}}, <br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\n  It was nice meeting you."}

Comment: @jeroen yes I am using the json_encode() ... but i just found out the answer as soon as you told me that I need to parse the json as a string so I used the following  data = JSON.parse(data); and it worked.

Comment: @json2021 I made a mistake with the `"json"` parameter, it is the fourth argument and not the third...

Comment: @jeroen  Its alright... I think think the $.post() can detect automatically..Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I was using json_encode() which was returning a json string.

So i just used  `data = JSON.parse(data);`

and it worked!

Below is what I did

$.post("mass_messaging.php",{template_id: template_id})

```
    .done(function(data){

       data = JSON.parse(data);

            console.log(data.msg);



    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
console.log(obj.msg);
```